# Process Spring Boot externalized property values

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the task of obfuscating passwords in our configuration files. While I don't think this is the right approach, managers disagree...

So the project I am working on is based on Spring Boot and we are using YAML configuration files. Currently the passwords are in plain text:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:sqlserver://DatabaseServer
        driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        username: ele
        password: NotTheRealPassword
```

The idea is to have some special syntax that supports an obfuscated or encrypted password:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:sqlserver://DatabaseServer
        driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        username: ele
        password: password(Tm90VGhlUmVhbFBhc3N3b3Jk)
```

In order for this to work I want to parse the property values using a regular expression and if it matches replace the value with the deobfuscated/decrypted value.

**But how do I intercept the property value?**

Comment: I don't think you can, if you're just using something built into Spring. However, if you're loading this YAML manually, then feeding it into Spring, do it there.

Comment: I suppose I could write my own PropertySource. I was hoping to find a mechanism that applies to all property sources.

Comment: You might be interested in [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1312)

Comment: Thanks for the link,  looks promising.  I'll try out some of the suggested approaches tomorrow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If finally got this to work. (Mainly thanks to [stephane-deraco](https://github.com/stephane-deraco) on [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1312))

Key to the solution is a class that implements `ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>`. I called it `PropertyPasswordDecodingContextInitializer`.

The main problem was to get spring to use this `ApplicationContextInitializer`. Important information can be found in the [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context). I chose the approach using a *META-INF/spring.factories* with following content:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=ch.mycompany.myproject.PropertyPasswordDecodingContextInitializer
```

The `PropertyPasswordDecodingContextInitializer` uses a `PropertyPasswordDecoder` and an implementing class, currently for simplicity a `Base64PropertyPasswordDecoder`.

**PropertyPasswordDecodingContextInitializer.java**

```
package ch.mycompany.myproject;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.env.CompositePropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.EnumerablePropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PropertyPasswordDecodingContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    private static final Pattern decodePasswordPattern = Pattern.compile("password\\((.*?)\\)");

    private PropertyPasswordDecoder passwordDecoder = new Base64PropertyPasswordDecoder();

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        for (PropertySource<?> propertySource : environment.getPropertySources()) {
            Map<String, Object> propertyOverrides = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            decodePasswords(propertySource, propertyOverrides);
            if (!propertyOverrides.isEmpty()) {
                PropertySource<?> decodedProperties = new MapPropertySource("decoded "+ propertySource.getName(), propertyOverrides);
                environment.getPropertySources().addBefore(propertySource.getName(), decodedProperties);
            }
        }
    }

    private void decodePasswords(PropertySource<?> source, Map<String, Object> propertyOverrides) {
        if (source instanceof EnumerablePropertySource) {
            EnumerablePropertySource<?> enumerablePropertySource = (EnumerablePropertySource<?>) source;
            for (String key : enumerablePropertySource.getPropertyNames()) {
                Object rawValue = source.getProperty(key);
                if (rawValue instanceof String) {
                    String decodedValue = decodePasswordsInString((String) rawValue);
                    propertyOverrides.put(key, decodedValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String decodePasswordsInString(String input) {
        if (input == null) return null;
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Matcher matcher = decodePasswordPattern.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String replacement = passwordDecoder.decodePassword(matcher.group(1));
            matcher.appendReplacement(output, replacement);
        }
        matcher.appendTail(output);
        return output.toString();
    }

}
```

**PropertyPasswordDecoder.java**

```
package ch.mycompany.myproject;

public interface PropertyPasswordDecoder {

    public String decodePassword(String encodedPassword);

}
```

**Base64PropertyPasswordDecoder.java**

```
package ch.mycompany.myproject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Base64PropertyPasswordDecoder implements PropertyPasswordDecoder {

    @Override
    public String decodePassword(String encodedPassword) {
        try {
            byte[] decodedData = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedPassword);
            String decodedString = new String(decodedData, "UTF-8");
            return decodedString;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


}
```

Mind you, the ApplicationContext has not finished initialized at this stage, so autowiring or any other bean related mechanisms won't work.

---

**Update:** Included @[jny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562721/jny)'s suggestions.

Comment: i noticed you used apache version of base64 instead of your code in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=.base64 why is that ?

Comment: Basically I didn't really care what implementation to use. We already use the apache commons libraries so I didn't notice that there is one in spring boot too.

Answer (score 4):

I used @[Daniele Torino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2784766/daniele-torino)'s answer and made several minor changes.

First, thanks to his link to the options on how to make spring recognize Initializer, I chose to do it in the `Application`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication application=new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    application.addInitializers(new PropertyPasswordDecodingContextInitializer());
    application.run(args);
}
```

Second, IDEA told me that that `else if (source instanceof CompositePropertySource) {` is redundant and it is because `CompositePropertySource` inherits from `EnumerablePropertySource`.

Third, I beleive there is a minor bug:  it messes up the order of property resolution. If you have one encoded property in environment, and another one in `application.properties` file the environment value will be overwritten with the `application.properties` value. 
I changed the logic to insert the decodedProperties right before encoded:

```
        for (PropertySource<?> propertySource : environment.getPropertySources()) {
                Map<String, Object> propertyOverrides = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                decodePasswords(propertySource, propertyOverrides);
                if (!propertyOverrides.isEmpty()) {
                       environment.getPropertySources().addBefore(propertySource.getName(), new MapPropertySource("decoded"+propertySource.getName(), propertyOverrides));
                }
        }
```

Comment: I have updated the answer to include your suggestions. Your answer seems to have a small bug, where you create two `MapPropertySource` - the second one taking `decodedProperties` as argument. The argument is expected to be a `Map` but is a `PropertySource<?>`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot, works out of the box

Answer (score 2):

***Inspired by @gogstad. Here is my major action in the spring boot project to encrypted my username and password and decrypted them in the project to work with tomcat:***

**1. In pom.xml file**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
    </dependency>
    …
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/classes</targetPath>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/classes</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    …
    </build>
```

**2. In App.java** (Note:to deploy the decryted springboot on tomcat, you should add the @ServletComponentScan annotation and extends the SpringBootServletInitializer)

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ServletComponentScan
    @EnableEncryptableProperties
    @PropertySource(name="EncryptedProperties", value = "classpath:config/encrypted.properties")
    public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        }

    }
```

**3. Encrypted your username and password and fill the application.properties file with the result：**

```
    java -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.2/jasypt-1.9.2.jar  org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI input="mypassword" password=mykey algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
```

*output is like the demo below:*

```
    java -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.2/jasypt-1.9.2.jar  org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI input="mypassword" password=mykey algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES

    ----ENVIRONMENT-----------------

    Runtime: Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.45-b02



    ----ARGUMENTS-------------------

    algorithm: PBEWithMD5AndDES
    input: mypassword
    password: mykey



    ----OUTPUT----------------------

    5XNwZF4qoCKTO8M8KUjRprQbivTkmI8H
```

**4. under the directory src/main/resources/config add two properties file：**

```
    a. application.properties
        spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx
        spring.datasource.username=ENC(xxx)
        spring.datasource.password=ENC(xxx)
        mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath:*/mapper/*.xml
        mybatis.type-aliases-package=com.xx.xxx.model
        logging.level.com.xx.xxx: DEBUG

    b. encrypted.properties
        jasypt.encryptor.password=mykey
```

Comment: OP wanted **encoding**, not encryption.

Answer (score -1):

Use spring cloud config server

Define encrypt.key=MySecretKey

Post message to encrypt https://config-server/encrypt

Define password now like

```
app.password={cipher}encryptedvalue
```

Use `@Value("${app.password}")` in code

and spring boot should give you decrypted value

Comment: 1. Using config server is a paradigm shift, not a solution to the problem OP is looking for.
2. He's looking for Base64 **encoding**, not encryption.