# encrypt value in properties file

Tags: java, spring, authentication, encryption

I have a password in the properties file which I want to encrypt using any 2 way encryption.

```
password = 123456
```

I use it in spring-security xml for active directory authentication. That time the password should be decrypted. Can some one point to me how to do this?

I am new to spring and I am not really sure what route to take here. I used Jasypt but I get LDAP authenticaton error 52 which means incorrect password. I assume the decryption is not happening correctly.

I'm using spring 4.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.7.RELEASE/reference/crypto.html Pretty much a step by step guide

Comment: I had a [similiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989883/process-spring-boot-externalized-property-values) problem recently. It's spring boot but it might help you or anyone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look [here](http://www.jasypt.org/spring31.html#Integrating_jasypt_with_Spring_Security_3.x). The major steps are :

1. define name space in your spring context xml file :

   `xmlns:encryption="http://www.jasypt.org/schema/encryption"`
2. define an encryptor :

   `<encryption:strong-password-encryptor id="passwordEncryptor" />`
3. instead of your *context:property-placeholder* tag, use :

   `<encryption:encryptable-property-placeholder encryptor="passwordEncryptor" location="classpath:application.properties"/>`
4. Now, you can use properties encrypted like the one below and the Encryptable Property Placeholder  will make sure that they get decrypted. Note that you need to encrypt the properties (passwords) with the same alghorithm (and the same configuration) as uses the defined encoder.

   `password=ENC(G6N718UuyPE5bHyWKyuLQSm02auQPUtm)`

Comment: Is this a valid namespace xmlns:encryption="http://www.jasypt.org/schema/encryption" ?

Comment: Yes. See [the link](http://www.jasypt.org/spring31.html#Integrating_jasypt_with_Spring_Security_3.x) I mentioned above.
Also, keep in mind that you need to add jasypt-spring31 artifact to the classpath. Unfortunately, Jasypt does not seem to provide support for Spring 4+

Comment: I think i wasted enough time trying the jasypt thing. going the traditional way.Writing a bean to decrypt password and injecting it into whatever needs the password

Comment: This is definitely an option. Then you can simply inject passwords like this : value="#{@passwordManager.decode('${my.encoded.password}')}"

Comment: Thanks Milos. The last comment definately helped me!

Answer (score 0):

An Answer to my question. I could not get it working with Jasypt after almost a day. So I wrote a simple AES encryption/Decryption.(Loads of examples on google)

Next in springsecurity.xml I simply added reference to the AES class like this

```
<beans:bean id="Decrypt" class="com.xxx.encoder.Decrypt">
    </beans:bean>
```

Next injected the password like this

```
<beans:bean id="contextSource"
class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="${host}" />
        <beans:property name="base" value="" />
        <beans:property name="userDn" value="${userDN}" />
        **<beans:property name="password" value="#{Decrypt.decrypt('${password}')}" />**
```

Passed the encryptted password in my properties file and it worked.

Comment: Hey @Priyanka Lopes, do you by any chance still have got this solution. i know its like 8 years past but just in case. Im stuck with similar prob