# configuring the encrypted database password in the spring datasource

Tags: spring

I am using spring with MyBatis to connect to Oracle database. I have `jdbc.properties` in which I am storing the username and password of the database.

I am using the below spring configuration to connect to oracle database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />



<beans profile="mybatis">
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="serverManagedDataSource" />

        <!-- <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> -->
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:mappers/**/*.xml" />
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="${url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    </bean>
```

In the properties file I had the password in the plain text format. Since its not a good idea to store the password in the plain text, I am planning to store an encrypted password in the properties file. If I encrypt the password, how can I decrypt it and map it to `{{password}}` field in the spring configuration. Please let me know.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989883/process-spring-boot-externalized-property-values