# decrypt springboot datasource password using own secret key before db connection

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Our company has an encryption utility that we want to use it as a universal encryption/decryption method. Our spring-boot application have an external properties to specify spring.datasource.* configurations.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" }),
                   @PropertySource(value = { "file:${application.properties}" }, ignoreResourceNotFound = true) })
```

Now, we want to decrypt it before connecting to the database. I have looked at spring-boot jasypt but it will not work if you want to use your own secret key as a decryption method. Is there a way to use the secretkey stored in the system that you already have for decryption?

I have encrypted and saved the password in the external properties in this Initializer

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyPasswordContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableWebApplicationContext> {

@Override
public void initialize(final ConfigurableWebApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    String configPath = applicationContext.getServletContext().getInitParameter("application.properties"));
    //load properties
    //encrypt if property is spring.datasource.password and starts with ## 
    //save properties file
}
```

Now encryption works fine. it is now finding a hook to implement the decryption process.

Comment: You can use EncryptionUtils class from Spring-security 2.0.7 or any latest release to implement the decryption process.

Comment: Thanks! I will read about it.

Comment: Hi @PraveenKumar, do you have any advise how to intercept database password to be decrypted before spring-boot's auto configure to database? I get a database connection error because it is connecting using the encrypted password.

Comment: you can refer to my another answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989883/process-spring-boot-externalized-property-values/44451676#44451676