# Spring Config Test with ApplicationContextInitializer - how to decrypt?

Tags: java, spring, encryption, spring-cloud-config

I have a test running against my Spring Config server to verify the application is working.  I did some manual tests and everything works just fine with a basic launch of the Spring Confg Boot application, but I want a unit test to prove the solution and be able to test my development keystore and whatnot.

I added a custom `ApplicationContextInitializer` implementation to load the data from `application-test.yml` at startup of the execution.  Everything works when the data is not encrypted; however, when I add an encrypted property, it does not decrypt it.

The implementation I used is:

```
public class TestYamlFileApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

  @Override
  public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    try {
      Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource(CLASSPATH_URI);
      YamlPropertySourceLoader sourceLoader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
      PropertySource<?> testProperties = sourceLoader.load("yamlTestProperties", resource, null);
      applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(testProperties);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

The `application-test.yml` is:

```
my:
  encrypted:
    parameter: '{cipher}AQB8C/1v9J+jPQZG...'

server:
  port: 0

spring:
  profiles:
    active: native

encrypt:
  key-store:
    location: classpath*:/security/development-test.jks
    alias: DevelopmentTest
    secret: SomeSecretPassword123
    password: SomeStorePassword123
```

My test is annotated with `@ContextConfiguration (initializers = TestYamlFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)` to kick it off.

The test runs a basic check using:

```
@Autowired
Environment env;

@Test
public void testStuff() {
  String theProp = env.getProperty("my.encrypted.parameter");
  System.err.println(theProp);
}
```

The output is:  `{cipher}AQB8C/1v9J+jPQZG...`

There are no exceptions listed.

What piece of the puzzle am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this an open issue at Spring. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12420. One possible solution has been provided at SO post [Process Spring Boot externalized property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989883/process-spring-boot-externalized-property-values)

Comment: Interesting.  I'm surprised they didn't run across this when writing their own tests in the project; but, we all miss something here and there.  Unfortunately, this is actually the answer!  Hopefully the bug is addressed in the next update.