# Configuring ssl keys for spring-cloud-config server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I want to set server.ssl.key-store-password for spring-cloud-config server and the configuration will come from GIT (application.yml).

Below is what i would like to configure in application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8760
  ssl:
    key-store: path to .jks
    key-store-password: '{cipher}encrypted password'
    key-store-type: jks
    key-password: '{cipher}encrypted password'
```

While bootstrapping config server it configures EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration with TextEncryptor FailsafeTextEncryptor which fails when decrypt function is called for EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.

How can we have our custom TextEncryptor for EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration such that I can use {cipher} while starting config-server

Referred https://stackoverflow.com/a/32047393/1946403

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm facing the exact same issue now.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error. To fix it, I had to add the EncryptionConfiguration and the TextEncryptor to the spring.factory file.

I have 3 files:

The encryption configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class AESEncryptionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer environmentDecryptApplicationInitializer() {
        return new EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer(new AESTextEncryptor());
    }
}
```

The TextEncryptor:

```
@Component
public class AESTextEncryptor implements TextEncryptor {

    @Override
    public String encrypt(String text) {
        .
        .
        .       
    }

    @Override
    public String decrypt(String encryptedText) {
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Then I had to add references to both files in `/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=com.rs.config.AESEncryptionConfiguration,com.common.encryption.AESTextEncryptor
```

By doing this, I was able to create custom ciphers.